# SocketTimeOutException while creating socket, java

Tags: java, sockets

I have created a sample java socket application.
 I used Socket `s = new Socket(ip, port)`    Now it works fine. but when my internet connection is very slow that time after a long interval (even if sometimes after 2 minutes) i used to get `SocketTimeOutException` in that line. means it gives that error while creating socket. I want the exception should be handled properly means if internet connection is very slow then if that error occurs it happens very late now .
I want if this type of error occurs then it should be caught very fast means the error should not come at such a delay interval of time rather it should come immediately.

How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decrease socket timeout like:

```
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com", 80), 500);
```

where 500 is timeout in milliseconds.

Here a snippet that uses Socket class:

```
 try { 
      InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
      int port = 80; SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
      Socket sock = new Socket(); 
      int timeoutMs = 500; 
      sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs); 
    } 
catch (SocketTimeoutException  e) { System.out.println("Timeout reached!");}
```